# Exception from DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate, almost identical MSDN example

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, dynamicmethod

When i call CreateDelegate(delegateType) i get a `System.ArgumentException`, which according to MSDN is because the delegateType has the wrong number of parameters or the wrong parameter types.

The strange part is the code I'm using is almost all copied from MSDN. My function as whole:

```
public static void AssertRaisesEvent(Action action, object obj, string eventName, NumberOfTimes numberOfTimesRaised)
{
    eventCounter = 0;
    EventInfo eventInfo = obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
    Type tDelegate = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;

    Type returnType = GetDelegateReturnType(tDelegate);
    if (returnType != typeof(void))
        throw new ApplicationException("Delegate has a return type.");

    var handler =
        new DynamicMethod("CompletedHandler",
            typeof(int),
            GetDelegateParameterTypes(tDelegate),
            obj.GetType());

    // Generate a method body. This method loads a string, calls 
    // the Show method overload that takes a string, pops the 
    // return value off the stack (because the handler has no
    // return type), and returns.
    //
    ILGenerator ilgen = handler.GetILGenerator();
    FieldInfo counterFieldInfo = typeof (AssertionHelpers).GetField("eventCounter",
                                                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, counterFieldInfo);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Complete the dynamic method by calling its CreateDelegate
    // method. Use the "add" accessor to add the delegate to
    // the invocation list for the event.
    //

    var delParams = GetDelegateParameterTypes(tDelegate);
    var handlerParams = handler.GetParameters();

    Delegate dEmitted = handler.CreateDelegate(tDelegate);
    eventInfo.GetAddMethod().Invoke(obj, new Object[] { dEmitted });

    ...
```

As you can see the comments are even there. As you also can see i have delParams and handlerParams variables which have the same number of parameters of the same type.

What is going on here?

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx

EDIT:
The event im trying to bind to:

```
private NullTransaction transaction;

public delegate void CompletedEventHandler(object testParam);

internal class NullTransaction : ITransaction
{
public event CompletedEventHandler Completed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // no implementation
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        // no implementation
    if(Completed != null)
            Completed.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the event you are trying to bind to? i.e. the thing with the event called `eventName`? also, note that you aren't currently storing the incremented counter

Comment: I have added some code to my post. What do you mean storing? I have the declaration outside the method.

Comment: with the changes I've cited, and your `Completed` event, I have it working and incrementing the counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most events don't return anything - in fact you **assert** that it has no return-type. You then declare your custom method (`handler`) as returning `int`, and try to bind it to a delegate that doesn't return an int. This won't work.

Also; your stack isn't valid for returning an int, since you "pop" the result.

i.e.  I created a test with

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

and bound to it; so then here:

```
Delegate dEmitted = handler.CreateDelegate(tDelegate);
```

you'll find that `tDelegate` is `EventHandler`. That doesn't match `handler`, which returns `int`.

---

Re the stack (comments); consider:

```
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, counterFieldInfo); <=== should be ldsfld, by the way
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1); // stack is now [counter] [1]
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Add); // stack is now [counter + 1]
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop); // stack is now empty
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // return
```

You've loaded two values, added them up, *thrown the result away*, and then returned. But you haven't returned the `int` that you claim to - this will fail IL inspection.

---

If you change:

```
var handler =
    new DynamicMethod("CompletedHandler",
        null,
        GetDelegateParameterTypes(tDelegate),
        obj.GetType());
```

and:

```
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, counterFieldInfo);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, counterFieldInfo);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

then it might work as you intend.

Also; this is simpler:

```
Delegate dEmitted = handler.CreateDelegate(tDelegate);
eventInfo.AddEventHandler(obj, dEmitted);
```

Comment: SO's members still amazes me. Thank you. Altough i am getting a new exception: ``FieldAccessException`` unless i change my eventCounter to a public field instead of a private (to be clear it works when i have it as a public). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Erik - sure; change the `obj.GetType()` in the `new DynamicMethod` call to the type that declares `counterFieldInfo`; the `owner` means "pretend I was in this class, in terms of what I am allowed to access". You could also skip the field-visibility check.

Comment: No matter, i solved it. The dynamic methods owner was the object in which the event was raised from. I haves it to the class where the private field is.

Comment: @Erik pretty sure I just said that ;p

Comment: Ah, didn't see you had answered. Thanks anyway!